# Seal interior gaps garage door

Tags: doors, garage, weatherstripping

I have weatherstripping/trim similar to this one on the outside of my (steel) residential garage door

[image: Current Weatherstripping]

However the current weatherstripping/trim does not seem to be sealing my door fully.  Basically, I am seeing gaps on the interior of my door where light is coming in from the outside.

How should I seal these gaps on the interior sides of my garage door?

Comment: Why not fix the problem with the exterior seal? There's no good way to seal around all the hardware inside a typical overhead door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently replaced all of the rollers and tracks and addressed a similar issue… if your air gaps are consistent from top to bottom, try reinstalling the trim/seal.
If the gaps are more accordion-like, it's fairly simple to adjust the hinge/roller hardware on the offending panel(s)
With the door closed (operator power off) loosen the top hinge slightly (just enough for the hinge to move freely),push the top door panel away from you, making it tight to the door seal. You'll see how the hinge can be adjusted to take up the slack, do one side at a time. Leave a sixteenth or so for movement and tighten the hinge.

For the rest of the door, you can loosen and move the straight section of door track to make a tighter seal. You may end up with a mis-alignment at the transition from straight track to curve, a little bending with pliers will solve that.

If the rollers are worn out, it's best to replace them first (Amazon,nylon,sealed bearings with dust covers).

Don't overdo the adjustment, the door seal will be damaged if the door drags too hard,as it moves along.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the current exterior weatherstripping and reinstall it (or new) correctly.

Perhaps with a dose of **adjust the door segments** if they are not lined up correctly with the doorframe while the door is sitting in the closed position. The surface of the closed door should be straight, so the seals can work as designed. That's either "obvious when you know to look for it" or "call a garage door company rather than DIY" depending on you.

Comment: I just replaced my exterior door weatherstripping last summer. The original had been installed about 25 years ago and was dried, cracking and the rubber seal was no longer flexible enough to actually seal. Made all the difference in the world.